# Magento $this-> function with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I created a page with product data, which is included in the home through the "require". When i open the home, it works perfectly.

```
<?php require ("$path/public_html/page.php"); ?>
```

But i have an AJAX code that includes this same page, with some extra functions, ex:

```
... .load('http://www.website.com/page.php?id='+code)
```

When the page is requested, it stops in the $this-> function and return 500 Internal Server Error:

```
 $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true,
```

Why the $this-> function does not work with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you do not understanding the OOP and how Magento works.  You cannot use the Magento application parts without initialization of Magento (Mage::run(...)).